# Xamarin Forms CollectionView ScrollTo Not working on Load

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I Have XAML form using a CollectionView.  I bind the view to a collection of date objects.  I set the SelectedItem in Code Behind which is working as expected.  I then try to use ScrollTo in code behind however it always displays the first item in the collection once the page is loaded.  After the page loads I have wired an image to fire the ScrollTo event and it works as expected.  Below is my code.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
'''
        for (int i = 0; i < 31 ; i++)
        {
            ScheduleDate date = new ScheduleDate();
            date._Date = dt.AddDays(i);
            colDates.Add(date);
        }

        cvDate.ItemsSource = colDates;
        cvDate.SelectedItem = colDates[10];
        cvDate.ScrollTo(cvDate.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Start, true)
'''
```

XAML Form

```
'''
            <CollectionView x:Name="cvDate" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                SelectionMode="Single" >
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Large"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
'''
```

Edit:

I wired up the OnCollectionViewScrolled event and when the following line of code is executed from OnAppearing()

cvDate.ScrollTo(cvDate.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);

OnCollectionViewScrolled is NOT being called.  However when I execute the same line of code from a button click event OnCollectionViewScrolled is being fired.

Comment: Please check the [CollectionView Scrolling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling) docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your `Description` and `_Date`. I make a simple example for your reference.

1. Trigger the ScrollTo in OnAppearing override method:

   ```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
       cvDate.ScrollTo(cvDate.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
    }
   ```
2. Trigger the ScrollTo with button click method:

   ```
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cvDate.ScrollTo(cvDate.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
    }
   ```

The whole code:

```
public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<ScheduleDate> colDates { get; set; }
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        colDates = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleDate>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
        {
            ScheduleDate date = new ScheduleDate();
            date.Description = i.ToString();
            colDates.Add(date);
        }

        cvDate.ItemsSource = colDates;
        cvDate.SelectedItem = colDates[10];
      

    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
       cvDate.ScrollTo(cvDate.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);

    }
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //cvDate.ScrollTo(cvDate.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
    }
}
public class ScheduleDate
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Update:**

```
 <ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
        x:Name="cvDate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding colDates}"
        SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Description}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have copied your code exactly and have the same issue.  Can I please see your XAML?

Comment: I have uploaded my xaml. Please check it. If you still have issue for this, i would upload my project.

Comment: I used your exact code and it still didn't work properly.  With that said I believe I figured out why, I'm using a MasterDetailPage setup.  When I take your code and place in Normal Content Page it works as expected.  At this point I'm guessing this is a bug.  I'm marking your answer as correct as it is.  If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it.  Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I have the same problem in a shell app - scrollto doesn't throw an error but doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I believe that at least on UWP you can't scroll to an element until it's actually been loaded by the UI.

In that case you could work around this with a CollectionView custom renderer.

You can override the `ItemsViewRenderer.ScrollTo` function and postpone the scroll until the target element has been loaded. To know when that happens you can register to the `ListViewBase.ContainerContentChanging` event.